# Problems on the generated value of the qr code into a input field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

JavaScript codes and HTML codes

I'm trying to put a generated value of the qr code a input text to be save in my SQLite database can't pust the darn value of the qr code

```js
var resultDiv;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

function init() {
    document.querySelector("#startScan").
        addEventListener("touchend", startScan, false);
 
 resultDiv = document.querySelector("#results");//works in <p id="results"></p>
 
 resultDiv = document.querySelector('#text4');//wont work at all <input id="text4" type="text" placeholder="Book Info"/>
 
}

function startScan() {

 cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        
        function (result) {
   var s = result.text.split('|');
            result.format;
   result.cancelled;

   resultDiv.innerHTML = s;
        }, 
        

  function (error) {
   alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
 );
 

}

JavaScript codes and HTML codes
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>qrBorrowers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <nav>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="add.html">Add</a>
            <a href="borrow.html">Borrow</a>
            <a href="return.html">Return</a>
            <a href="generate.html">QR code</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <Label>
        <h1> &nbsp; Borrow a Book </h1>
    </Label>

    <div class="borrow">


        <input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Borrower Number" onfocus="this.value=''"/>

        <input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Borrower Last Name" onfocus="this.value=''" />

        <input id="text3" type="text" placeholder="Borrower First Name" onfocus="this.value=''" />

        <input id="text4" type="text" placeholder="Book Info"/>

        <input id="text6" type="date" placeholder="Date Borrowed" />

        <br>

    </div>

    <div class="borrow">
        
        <p id="results"></p>

        <button id="startScan">Start Scan</button>

        <button id="savedb">Save </button>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scanQR.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inner HTML it will not going to save your generated QR code to input box. You need to change the innerHTML to value to save the value in input box such that you can use that when form submit as value to save in database.

```js
var resultDiv;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

function init() {
    document.querySelector("#startScan").
        addEventListener("touchend", startScan, false);
 
 resultDiv = document.querySelector("#results");//works in <p id="results"></p>
 
 resultDiv = document.querySelector('#text4');//wont work at all <input id="text4" type="text" placeholder="Book Info"/>
 
}

function startScan() {

 cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        
        function (result) {
   var s = result.text.split('|');
            result.format;
   result.cancelled;

   resultDiv.value = s;
        }, 
        

  function (error) {
   alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
 );
 

}

JavaScript codes and HTML codes
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>qrBorrowers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <nav>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="add.html">Add</a>
            <a href="borrow.html">Borrow</a>
            <a href="return.html">Return</a>
            <a href="generate.html">QR code</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <Label>
        <h1> &nbsp; Borrow a Book </h1>
    </Label>

    <div class="borrow">


        <input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Borrower Number" onfocus="this.value=''"/>

        <input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Borrower Last Name" onfocus="this.value=''" />

        <input id="text3" type="text" placeholder="Borrower First Name" onfocus="this.value=''" />

        <input id="text4" type="text" placeholder="Book Info"/>

        <input id="text6" type="date" placeholder="Date Borrowed" />

        <br>

    </div>

    <div class="borrow">
        
        <p id="results"></p>

        <button id="startScan">Start Scan</button>

        <button id="savedb">Save </button>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scanQR.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the value in input box should not use "resultDiv.innerHTML = s;"
Rather you should use "resultDiv.value = s" which will save your code to input box which you can use to save in SQLite Database.